# Help with HTACCESS redirection to HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have inherited a web app. It's running fine. But it's using HTTP, not HTTPS. This is the `.HTACCESS` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] </IfModule>
```

HTACCESS files are not my area of expertise. What I think this is doing is, "if there is NO specific file name, redirect to INDEX.PHP including any query string, then stop processing rewrite rules.

We need the page to default to `index.php` as it does, but if other links are specified, do not redirect to `index.php`.

What I need to do is this:

1. If no page is specified, default to `HTTPS://example.com/index.php` (with query string if any)
2. If a page IS specified, redirect it to HTTPS if it is NOT already on HTTPS.

In other words, the entry point should redirect to `index.php` over HTTPS, and every specified page should redirect over HTTPS (including query strings).

Something so simple, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: You have a stray `</IfModule>` - can you clarify whether you have anything else in the file, eg. a corresponding opening `<IfModule>` tag perhaps? Can you clarify what you mean by "page"? Is this _any_ URL-path? Or a URL that maps to an actual file?

Comment: Typo. "We need the application to default to HTTPS://example.com/index.php (with query string if any), or to redirect any specified other pages to HTTPS. Yes, I saw the stray Ifmodule. that was there before I arrived. just cleaned that part up.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] </IfModule>
> ```

What this says is... for all requests (`^`) that do not map to an actual file (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) then *internally rewrite* the request to `index.php` (ie. the "front-controller").

The `QSA` (Query String Append) flag is not actually required here, since you aren't specifying a query string on the *substitution* (it's just `index.php`). The query string on the request will be available by default.

The stray `</IfModule>` on the end of the line will simply be ignored in this instance. But yes, that should be removed, which I believe you have done already.

Providing this already routes your URLs as required within your application then there is nothing else you need to change with your existing code.

---

The HTTP to HTTPS *external redirect* is a separate thing and should go *before* the existing directives. As a general rule, *external redirects* always go before *internal rewrites*.

By the sounds of it, you just need a standard "redirect everything to HTTPS". The specific code you need to use can depend on how the SSL cert is managed for your site (eg. whether a front-end proxy is being used etc.), but otherwise, if the SSL cert is installed directly on your application server then it's just a standard HTTP to HTTPS redirect, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You might also consider canonicalising the www/non-www at the same time.

Comment: That is working, but now the URL displays index.php on all urls. What used to be example.com/login is now being redirected using https to https://example.com/index.php/login. Is there a way to hide the index.php from view so that it's just https://example.com/login. (I dont' know why this commenting system is removing the HTTPS prtion of the url i'm typing in. the https redirect is working. but now it's dispalying index.php in all urls where before, it only displays if the example.com url is typed in. otherwise, it would display the domain/route (it's a laravel app)

Comment: so if i typed in example.com it use to redirect to example.com/index.php which would then transform to example.com/login (a laravel app route). but it now shows example.com/index.php/routename on all urls. basically, i do have all pages with what you put going over https, but it's inserting index.php visibly in the urls. How do I hide index.php and just show example.com/route

Comment: It looks like you might have the directives in the wrong order? As mentioned above, the HTTP to HTTPS redirect _must_ go before your existing directives, otherwise, this will indeed expose `index.php` since the request is first _rewritten_ to `index.php` before then triggering an external redirect to `index.php` (which would probably break your Laravel routing?) If you want to include code/URL in a comment then surround it in backticks (``).

Comment: Also, make sure you clear your browser cache. Any erroneous 301 redirects will have been cached hard by the browser. It can often be easier to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason. (Or make sure caching is _disabled_ whilst testing.)

Comment: If you were seeing a redirect to `example.com/index.php/routename` it looks like you were seeing a cached response from the code in @deltavin's answer. (?)

Answer (score 0):

You are right on your assumption

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   --> if the f(ile) doesn't exists, 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] </IfModule> --> redirect to index.php
```

For the rules you want, try this and let us know:

```
//redirect all pages to /index.php
RedirectMatch 301 /*(.*) /index.php/$1  [EDIT: don't use this. Use your first rule + this http->https rule below]

//Rewrite to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also consider this boilerplate that explains and implements all relevant concepts needed to run a contemporary website. It includes security, XSS prevention, caching among other things. I am suggesting this because the htaccess you've inherited is very minimal.
URL: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

Comment: If I use that, I get a loop repeating redirection to index.php.

Comment: I think I know why that's happening. The first rule is redirecting all traffic to index.php. So, let's remove that and use the following:            
//redirect all pages to /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L] </IfModule>

//Rewrite to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]              Difficult to format the code in a comment box.  What I mean is, use your rule followed by the second rule I suggested. Ignore the first rule from my two rules.

Comment: Lastly, htaccess config needs some trial and error. Try rules from this generator where you can formulate your own rules: https://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: @deltavin Please edit your answer, rather trying to stuff code blocks in a comment. (Certainly trying to 301 redirect to `index.php`, passing the URL-path as PATH_INFO is _very wrong_! Advisable to never mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias directives in the same context - the mod_rewrite directives still execute first, despite the apparent order in `.htaccess`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Removed the L from the first rewrite rule so that the second also would work. The first directs any unspecified page to index.php, the second rewrite rule redirects to use https.

Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: These directives are in the wrong order. An external redirect (the 2nd rule block) triggers an entirely separate request from the client - the earlier _rewrite_ is effectively lost, until the second request is processed and the request is rewritten to `index.php` again. Except on the second request, the redirect does not occur (because you are now on HTTPS) so it "works".

Comment: So I should simply swap the rules?

Comment: Yes, just swap the rules - so the external redirect is first. It will still work as before, except a little bit more efficiently. As mentioned in my answer, the `QSA` flag is not required on that `RewriteRule`. You can add the `L` flag back if you wish (it is _implied_ anyway if it is the last `RewriteRule` directive in the file). However, if you don't include the `L` flag now and later add more directives then you _might_ get problems.